# What is the proper way to implement a REST API for Search by multiple criteria?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

What is the proper way to implement a REST API for Search by multiple criteria?  For example, a User search may include fields like:

```
FirstName
LastName
EmailAddress
PhoneNumber
```

`"users/"` would be the base collection.

Answer (score 1):

The way should be - **use** some existing *(or even your own)* **querying API**. There is already solution pushed by Microsoft - OData.

> [How to create OData endpoints in Web API. OData is a data access protocol for the web. It provides a uniform way to query and manipulate data sets. Web API supports both Version 3 and Version 4 of the OData protocol.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api)

In a nutshell, we can use options like **`$filter`**, **`$top`**, **`$orderby`**, **`$select`**... like this

```
http://host:port/path/SampleService.svc/Categories(1)/Products
?$top=2&$orderby=Name&$filter=Name+eq+'Abc'
```

Read more also here:

- [Basic Tutorial](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/)
- [How to Use Web API OData to Build an OData V4 Service without Entity Framework](http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Preferred way is to do a POST with body having search fields or you can also do With a GET like

.../users/f={name=xyz;id=123}

something like this.